# What a phosphor screen looks like after being hit by a single electron?

Tags: electrons, fluorescence

As I read on Wikipedia, a phosphor coating of a CRT screen lights up because an electron in one of the phosphor atoms emits light when it goes down from its excited state.

When a single electron hits a phosphor coating, is it the case that exactly one atom of the screen will glow? If not, what is the shape of the spot on the screen for a single electron?

Comment: Depends on how energetic that incoming electron is and what angle it hits the screen at. Typically it will excite a volume of the material, and the higher the incident energy the larger the volume.